# Declaring const in a function do not throw error?

Tags: javascript, scope

Why can we declare a const in a function and call the function multiple times **without getting an error**

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'newTab' has already been declared

It is creating a new const every time we call the function?

Code to illustrate :

```js
function foo() {
  const newTab = [123]
  console.log(newTab);
}
```

Thanks if someone can enlighten me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each function call will create a new block *(Since the javascript is interpreted language and runs the code line by line so each function call will create a local execution context exactly where the function gets invoked)* in memory *(The last one will be removed in the garbage collection phase)*, so each instance of `const newTab` is separate from the previous one. It may seem it should throw an error due to the nature of defining the `const` element, but since the last one is removed and a new one is in the new memory block, so it will not throw any error.

**NOTE:** This [article](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/learn-javascript-fundamentals-scope-context-execution-context-9fe8673b3164#:%7E:text=Local%20Execution%20Context%20is%20created,(not%20defining%20a%20function).&text=When%20the%20JS%20engine%20starts,known%20as%20global%20variable%20environment.) and this [video](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjWir_H64PrAhWHjqQKHbs4C04QwqsBMBF6BAgLEAg&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3Dexrc_rLj5iw&usg=AOvVaw2VcyMEfNHTiWVXxXGmaTqi) may help you to learn more about local execution context.

Comment: I was thinking about memory but my knowledge wasn't sufficient enough!
Thank you for this perfect response, I'm more confident with that now, have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function foo() {
        const newTab = [123];
        console.log(newTab);
      }
      foo();
      foo();
      foo();
```

Actually your code works fine, i can't see any errors, how do you call it? Every call const newTab will be created in local execution context where all variable isolated

Comment: J.doe who asked this question is actually curious why it didn't failed so he was expecting it to not throw any error.

Comment: I think my answer includes reason why, as well :)

Comment: Yes it does, and you explained it well. I explicitly thought of mentioning this to you and as a part I also made edit to make error look clear. Thanks Anna